# ReactJS: Access context from base component

Tags: javascript, class, reactjs

I'm trying to create a base component that can handle UI themes.  The theme is passed to components via context, but the base component that I've created is not receiving the context.

```
class DetailView extends ThemedComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return <div>Detail View</div>;
  }
}

export default DetailView;

class ThemedComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props);
    // context here is undefined
  }
}

ThemedComponent.contextTypes = {
  theme: PropTypes.object,
};

export default ThemedComponent;
```

I can get the context from DetailView if it extends Component directly and all that works fine.  However, when I try to get the context within ThemedComponent it is always undefined.

What's the right way to create a common base component that can perform operations using the components context?

Comment: you have a typo: `render {` instead of `render () {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass context to `super` in DetailView:

```
class DetailView extends ThemedComponent {
     constructor(props, context) {
          super(props, context);
     }
     .........
}
```